# Find and Upsert Using the Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to migrate code from the old MongoDB driver to the latest version.
In the old version we had something like this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("foo", "foo");
int value = 1;
BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject("seq", value);
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$inc", field);
DBObject o = getDBCollection().findAndModify(query, null, null, false, update, true, true);
```

If the 'foo' document did not exist then it would be created.
If it did exist the value of seq would be incremented.

From what I can determine to do the same thing using MongoCollection I need to use replaceOne and do something like this:

```
Document query = new Document("foo", "foo");
int value = 1;
Document field = new Document("seq", value);
Document update = new Document("$inc", field);
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
UpdateResult ret = getMongoCollection().replaceOne(query, update, options);
```

but this gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name $inc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You want [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions-):

```
FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions()
    .upsert(true)
    .returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);

UpdateResult ret = getMongoCollection().findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

The `.replaceOne()` means exactly that and "replaces" the entire document ( except the `_id` ) with the content provided. That means modifiers like `$inc` are not allowed here.

So you use `.findOneAndUpdate()` instead. Note that you likely want `ReturnDocument.AFTER` to return the "modified" document rather than the "original" document before the update was applied, which would be the default action.

Comment: That worked - thank you. I had tried using findOneAndUpdate earlier but I didn't have those options; that was the clincher.